# How to keep time zone constant for a given date using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to convert below date in EST Time zone. Currently it is picking up my system time zone which is PST resulting in change of date. Instead of changing the date I want to keep the time zone constant for the below date. I have gone through many forums but not getting the exact solution or close to it.

```
describe("Day Entry1", () => {
  it("should be created with an entryDate1", () => {
    const dayEntry = new DayEntry(new Date("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00")); // Can i keep dayEntry constant to EST?  
    expect(dayEntry.entryDate).toEqual("2021-01-01"); 
  });
```

//Its failing as expected is coming as 2020-12-31

Comment: Consider using a date time library that supports time zones like [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). You will avoid a bunch of pain (read DST).

Comment: What is `DayEntry`? That's where the change needs to be made; it's converting the `Date` to a string in another time zone.

Comment: Moment is no longer supported. Consider Luxon. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/